# Is it possible to launch an Activity Extension directly in code without using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios

So far as I can tell, the only way to launch an Activity Extension is to present an ActivityViewController which will allow the user to select an activity.

Since I have provided my own custom Activity Extension (as a separate app), I would like to launch it directly from my host app without making the user select it.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can post to twitter and facebook using  SLComposeViewController .